# Use Zip Class in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp, zip, cakephp-3.0

I would like use the standard PHP Zip class in an entity in CakePHP.

I call `$zip = new ZipArchive();`

But i have an error.

> *Error: Class 'App\Controller\ZipArchive' not found*

How add/use this class ?

It's probably a problem of namespace but i don't know how configure it...

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class ArchivesController extends AppController
{
...
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you mean the standard PHP `ZipArchive` class or some CakePHP utility? Because the former belongs to root namespace. In any case, it's impossible to say what's wrong with your code if you hide it from us. Please edit the question and provide some information.

Comment: "It's probably a problem of namespace but i don't know how configure it..." - and you haven't thought about that this might be a good moment to read http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the leading backslash:

```
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
```

Namespaces are not too different from file system paths. If you have this:

```
mkdir /foo.txt
cd /home/jim
```

... you can't do this:

```
type foo.txt
```

You need:

```
type /foo.txt
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to add the leading backslash as you said, but get an error:

> Error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found 

Also tried to put  `use  ZipArchive;` after `namespace App\Controller;` but it won't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
use ZipArchive;
```

at the beginning of your Controller File.

Comment: This! Could not make it work without this, I never thought I'd need to actually include it. Thank you!